# Elementor remove padding value

Tags: elementor

I have accidentally modified paddings of an element in responsive mode for mobile breakpoint only, and after I saved it I cannot unset the value anymore. All other breakpoints don't have any padding value set. All I can do from that Elementor customizer it to set it to some fixed value, but that's stupid. I need to UNSET ANY VALUE so that it will rely on paddings defined by theme. See screenshot

[image]

Is there any better way for me rather than removing it from DB?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way how to unset the value. So I just changed the units to "%" and saved. Was an easy fix but not obvious